# How to update SPARK broadcast value on worker node?

Tags: java, apache-spark, broadcast

I have a broadcast value got from database. I define the broadcast on the driver master

```
val stampsBroadcast = ssc.sparkContext.broadcast(stampListMap)
```

This value (`stampsBroadcast.value`) was used on the worker node executors. Once the executor finish the task (add new key to the database). I need update the broadcast value to add this new key.

I tried to use:

```
stampsBroadcast.unpersist(false)
ssc.sparkContext.broadcast(NewstampsBroadcastValue)
```

but it seems I can't use `ssc` on the worker nodes. If I re-broadcast on the driver master, how can I get the new data from the worker nodes?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create a broadcast variable from the worker nodes.

In your case, basically you need [Accumulators](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#accumulators). Define the accumulator on the Driver. On the worker nodes you can update the accumulator value. Again you can fetch the updated value on the Driver.

Note:you cannot retrieve the value of accumulator on the worker nodes. Only updated of value is possible from worker nodes.

Below an example from spark docs:

```
// creating the accumulator on driver
scala> val accum = sc.longAccumulator("My Accumulator")
accum: org.apache.spark.util.LongAccumulator = LongAccumulator(id: 0, name: Some(My Accumulator), value: 0)

// updating the accumulator on worker nodes
scala> sc.parallelize(Array(1, 2, 3, 4)).foreach(x => accum.add(x))
...
10/09/29 18:41:08 INFO SparkContext: Tasks finished in 0.317106 s

// fetaching the value
scala> accum.value
res2: Long = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

First: Update the spark to spark2.3

Second: Make the stampListMap as file stream (`sparkStream.readStream.textFile('/../my.txt')...load()`), the file stream can self update the content itself. And if now you use stream join static,you can use stream join stream in spark2.3+.